# Can you transfer a running Minecraft server from one machine to another

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, pi

Sorry if this isn’t the right place to ask this, but:

I have a Minecraft server on a Mac laptop which ideally would run 24/7 aside from daily reboots. When I close the laptop it won’t let anybody connect.

Is it possible to either allow connections while the laptop is closed or transfer the running server to a raspberry pi?

Ideally the server wouldn’t have to restart during that transfer but if that’s not possible it’s not too big of an issue, but what would be the best way to transfer the files? I already have set up ssh but I am not sure exactly how to transfer files. Ideally i also wouldn’t boot the pi to desktop but just the CLI.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic on SO, as it isn't really about programming. That said, I'm not super familiar with Macs. But, could you tell it to not go to sleep when the lid is closed? Or, why not just run it entirely on the Pi? That is likely to work fine too. You can't (practically) transfer it while it is running. But you could stop the server, transfer the files to the Pi, and then start it on the Pi. Look up the `scp` command.

Comment: @cocomac ok thanks, I will look into scp. Also, do you know where a better place to ask questions like this would be? It isn’t really gaming or programming but something in between